# CSS Cascade Menu: Position <div> relative to <li>

Tags: html, css, menu

I want to build a cascade menu where at a certain `<li>` a new menu is opened. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div className='ux-dropdown-menu-container'>
<ul className='ux-dropdown-menu'>
  <li className='ux-dropdown-menu-item'><a href='#'>Menu Item 1</a></li>
  <li className='ux-dropdown-menu-item'><a href='#'>Menu Item 2</a></li>
  <li className='ux-dropdown-menu-item'><a href='#'>Submenu</a></li>
  <li className='ux-dropdown-menu-item'>
    <div className='ux-dropdown-menu-container'>
          <ul className='ux-dropdown-menu'>
            <li className='ux-dropdown-menu-item'><a href='#'>SubMenu Item 1</a></li>
            <li className='ux-dropdown-menu-item'><a href='#'>SubMenu Item 2</a></li>
            <li className='ux-dropdown-menu-item'><a href='#'>SubMenu Item 3</a></li>
            <li className='ux-dropdown-menu-item'>
            </li>
          </ul>
  </div>
  </li>
   <li className='ux-dropdown-menu-item'><a href='#'>Menu Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And my CSS classes:

```
.ux-dropdown-menu-container {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-color: $ux-color-boxed-background;
    border: solid;
    border-color: $ux-color-border;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px $ux-color-border;
    top: 105%;
    text-align: left;
    min-width: 100px;
}

.ux-dropdown-menu {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; // top right botton left
    z-index: 1;
}

.ux-dropdown-menu-item
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}


.ux-dropdown-menu-item a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: $ux-color-text;
}


.ux-dropdown-menu-item:hover {
    background-color: $ux-color-hover;
}

.ux-dropdown-menu-item:active {
    background-color: $ux-color-click-background;
}
```

Even having a position: relative at my `<li>`, the new `<div>` for the submenu is not positioning there. Here is the result:

[image]

I expected the submenu to appear right at the side of the `Submenu` item.

I am now looking to:

(A) position the submenu right next to the `Submenu` item

(B) consider right or left opening, in case the menu is composed and the right side of the screen, where it then needs to open the menu to the left. I do not plan to use jQuery

Comment: I suggest not using that style of submenus since you will have trouble with responsive design. Also how do you open the menu if you dont use javascript or jquery?

Comment: The menu opening is not part of the issue here. I will be using ReactJs for that. Please explain the submenu styling vs responsive design problem...

Comment: Well when you are resizing the browser you will have to consider the submenu going left or right to not be too wide or too far off because you will have your text cut off otherwise

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
 margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.ux-dropdown-menu-container {
 float: left;
}

.ux-dropdown-menu-containerItem {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: $ux-color-boxed-background;
    border: solid;
    border-color: $ux-color-border;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px $ux-color-border;
    top: 0;
    text-align: left;
    min-width: 100px;
 left: 100%;
}

.ux-dropdown-menu-item:hover .ux-dropdown-menu-containerItem {
    display: block;
}

.ux-dropdown-menu {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; // top right botton left
    z-index: 1;
}

.ux-dropdown-menu-item
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 list-style: none;
}


.ux-dropdown-menu-item a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: $ux-color-text;
}


.ux-dropdown-menu-item:hover {
    background-color: $ux-color-hover;
}

.ux-dropdown-menu-item:active {
    background-color: $ux-color-click-background;
}
```

```html
<div class="ux-dropdown-menu-container">
<ul class="ux-dropdown-menu">
  <li class="ux-dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="ux-dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  <li class="ux-dropdown-menu-item">
   <a href="#">Submenu</a>
    <div class="ux-dropdown-menu-containerItem">
          <ul class="ux-dropdown-menu">
            <li class="ux-dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">SubMenu Item 1</a></li>
            <li class="ux-dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">SubMenu Item 2</a></li>
            <li class="ux-dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">SubMenu Item 3</a></li>
          </ul>
  </div>
  </li>
   <li class="ux-dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain the solution you are doing, not only code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: Sorry I thought you will under stand by looking the code. 

I will try to explain For  dropdown menu ".ux-dropdown-menu-containerItem"  give "top: 0; left: 100%;"